Problems creating Laravel project with Composer - OpenSSL Extension Issue
It started when I wanted to create a new Laravel project, but the terminal produced a response like the following:

This is the response:
"The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true."
I am trying to create a new Laravel project using command
composer create-project laravel/laravel new-project

However, the terminal responds as shown in the picture above. I thought there was a problem with my laptop settings, because my friend also used the same version of Laravel and installed it in the same way, but it worked and didn't have any problems.
Apart from that, what is the best solution to the problem of creating this Laravel project? So that I won't experience problems like this in the future. Thank you very much.

You need to enable openssl extension. Remove the semicolon before extension=openssl in php.ini file.
